# Flask - Can i perform another request in the middle of an AJAX call.

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

So i have an ajax function in my javascript that posts to my flask backend.

Can I succesffuly make the call to /another_ajax_url ?

```
@app.route('/myroute', methods=['POST, GET'])
def test():
    a = 2 + 2
    requests.post('/another_ajax_url', data = a)
    #do the other stuff and return to /myroute
    b = 3 + 3
    return jsonify(b=b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but you may prefer to use something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) if you don't need the result.

Doing an http request inside the client request will block the client until the request is completed and the remaining of your code executed.

Comment: Celery looks like what I need actually. Thanks.